# String Table vs2008 generate Unicode strings

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, unicode, resources

How can I set VS2008 String Editor generate wide strings?

By default it generates like this:

```
...
STRINGTABLE 
BEGIN
    IDS_HELLO_ASCII_STR "Hello"
END
...
```

But I want set VS2008 String Editor to generate wide string like this:

```
...
STRINGTABLE 
BEGIN
    IDS_HELLO_UNICODE_STR L"Hello"
END
...
```

In [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381050%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says that "To encode Unicode characters, use an "L" followed by the Unicode characters enclosed by quotes."

Does anybody know how set VS2008 generate wide strings?

**UPD**: There is no other way to edit with String Editor. You must use a text editor to edit .rc files if you want wide strings in the string tables.

Comment: There is no reason to do that. If you need Unicode strings, you can convert the whole file to UTF-16. The editor will preserve that, and you will be able to use any Unicode characters in a readable way (better than the escaped form described in the documentation)

Comment: @MihaiNita I need insert to the string 0x2063 (for example) an unicode character. Do you have any idea how insert it to the string using String Editor?

Comment: Open the file with the text editor.  Use an L to make it a Unicode string, embed special characters with `\xuuuu` where uuuu is the hexadecimal codepoint.

Comment: @HansPassant Of course, this way obvious. It doesn't solve the problem. If you try to edit (add new string for example) and save the string table with String Editor - the strings will be ASCII again.

Comment: Do pursue the obvious, like not editing with the GUI editor anymore.

Comment: itn's kosher way ;) (it is inadmissible for me)

Comment: There is no other way. String editor does not have desired functionality. Put all strings in additional .rc2 file to prevent editor from changing them. Edit .rc2 file manually.

Comment: @Dialecticus Thx, It's bad news.

Comment: "I need insert to the string 0x2063 (for example) an unicode character. Do you have any idea how insert it to the string using String Editor?" => First, make sure you save you .rc file as Unicode UTF-16. Then you can insert it any way you want (although U+2063 is INVISIBLE SEPARATOR, so probably not very useful :-). You can (for instance) copy/paste from CharMap.

Comment: @MihaiNita yeap, "INVISIBLE SEPARATOR" it is exactly that char what I want %) And of course I changed .rc encoding into UTF-16. Please look at my 4th comment from the top.